# How to use hex escapes in bash eval string?

Tags: linux, bash, encoding, hex, eval

I am trying to execute a command in a string that contains hexadecimal escape sequences such as `\x20`.

For example, if the string is `ls\x20/usr/bin/`, then I want to run the command `ls /usr/bin/`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the readable way contains 3 lines:

```
CMD="ls\x20/usr/bin/"
OUTPUT="$(echo -e $CMD)"
eval "${OUTPUT}"
```

the `echo -e` will convert the string and the converted string will be stored in OUTPUT.
then just use eval :)

Hope it will help you

In one line (just as you said):

```
$(echo -e "ls\x20/usr/bin/")
```

Note: this way is one line but it doesn't work with everything..
It won't work with aliases for example.

Comment: Hi I-V, that's exactly what i need. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It worked with one line. $(echo -e 'ls\x20/usr/bin')